# Conver varchar value as Time in oracle

Tags: oracle, select, time, varchar

I have numerical string in  varchar column need to return those values in time format

```
Time
----
1560
1350
1561
```

output should be like below

```
time
----
00:15:60
00:13:50
00:15:61
```

im not good in database..can any one help me to return like this...

Comment: 00:15:60 is not a valid hour format... what do you mean? 15minutes and 60seconds? why not use 16minutes instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

00:15:60 is not a valid hour format... what do you mean? 15minutes and 60seconds? why not use 16minutes instead?

anyway, after you fix the value of seconds passed in, use the query below

```
select
     to_char(
       to_date('001500','HH24MISS')
     ,'HH24:MI:SS')
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, DATE columns (and related types, like TIMESTAMP) always include year, month, day, hour, minute and second. 
You can't have a DATE without having all of them.
You can, however, specify a DATE without specifying all of them: the parts that you leave out will get default values. If you don't specify a month, it defaults to the current month. If you don't give a day, it defaults to the 1st of the month.

If that doesn't suit your needs, use some data type other than DATE.